# Redirect on null getParameter

Tags: html, forms, jsp

I have the below code in my .jsp file. I have an html form that post to this jsp. I would like to check if the parameter is null and redirect back to the form if it is null and also if it contains letters. The below conditional doesn't seem to work. It just ignores this and submits the sql with a null value.

Where am I going wrong?

```
 if(request.getParameter("formPost") == null)
           response.sendRedirect("index.html");

   else
        PostVar = request.getParameter("formPost");
```

Comment: can you post some more code for better insight

Comment: Try adding a `return;` after your redirect.

Comment: Is it really `PostVar = request.getParameter("formPost");`?  That wont compile.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski Thats just an example, but it doesn't really matter, its just var names.

Comment: In JSP?  I thought you'd need a *type* too. So: `String PostVar = request.getParameter("formPost");`

Comment: ...Ah so 'PostVar' is _already_ declared?  It looked like a class.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be hard pressed to get `response.sendRedirect` to work in a JSP, unless you're being really old-school and doing *everything* in JSP and are experienced with doing so.

`response.redirect` needs to be done before any textual 'response body' output has been committed to the output stream.  In JSP, this includes new-lines/carriage returns, any unprocessed content that passes through the JSP engine direct to the browser.

Just putting a taglib declaration at the top followed by a new line will start building a response body and then any subsequent response header manipulations will be too late.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
if(request.getParameter("formPost") != null && !request.getParameter("formPost").equals(""))         {     
    String postVar = request.getParameter("formPost"); 
} else {
    response.sendRedirect("index.html");     
}
```